# What is the difference between subvolcanic rocks and plutonic rocks?

Tags: geology, rocks, magmatism

I'm studying Plutonic (Intrusive) rocks and I really don't understand the difference between Plutonic Rocks that form in Sills and Dikes from the so called  subvolcanic rocks, also known as a hypabyssal rocks. Aren't they the same? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main difference between a subvolcanic verses a  plutonic is depth at which the rock solidified at from its molten state.  Plutonic implies a depth greater than subvolcanic by definition but I am sure there is some overlap between shallow end of plutonic and subvolcanic.  Depth of emplacement for plutonic would mostly be much greater than 2 km.

[Plutonic](https://www.azomining.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=1287) is an igneous rock formed by solidification at considerable depth beneath the earth's surface.

Subvolcanic rock, also known as a hypabyssal rock, is an intrusive igneous rock that is emplaced at medium to shallow depths (<2 km) within the crust.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea. But in the last line shouldn't it be "(<2 km)"?

Comment: What confuses me is that dikes and sills are by deffinition plutonic structuctures ( at least from where i am studying; Tarbuck). And it says that they DO form at shallow depths. So, they should be subvolcanics.